# LocalDB requires SQL Server 2016 LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, database, localdb, sql-server-2016-localdb

I have written an addin for my company using a local database. I am now in the stage of deploying it to other users using a setup so I can set the prerequisites. So far so good.

The issue I am having is that for some reason the database requires SQL Server 2016 LocalDB to be installed. Other users already have SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB. In the prerequisites of the setup I put 2016, but for some reason the download is not functioning. It gives an error on the download (hresult 2146697203 in the log file). I read somewhere that there is no redistributable avialabe for 2016 and 2017. So I tried it with 2019. This is downloading and installing, but my database is not working. It wants 2016 for some reason.

My question(s):

- Is it possible to change the local database to 2019 or 2014 Express?
- Or do I need another bootstrapper for 2016?
- Or is there another option I am missing/overlooking?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15 there is a link there for the installer. You can install it as a named instance so it doesn't interfere with other installations

Comment: I found the installers and when I install 2016 and then my application, it works. The thing is I don't want the users to run two setups. I want the setup of the right LocalDB Server as a prerequisite in my setup. But the bootstrapper for 2016 is not working.

Comment: You want a silent install then, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15 something along the lines of `sqlserversetup /features=LocalDB`